# How to update the data of a goroutine when the data it use are being updated by the user

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

I currently have two services, one 'reactor' that launch goroutines that listen to some action and run indefinitely in a loop. The data it use come from the service 'entreprise'

What I'm trying to do is to eliminate the need to stop and restart 'reactor' to incorporate the updates to some machine and group configuration (coming from 'entreprise'). After launching, 'reactor' will periodically retrieve the list of machine groups/machines from 'entreprise' and adjust its monitoring mechanism to reflect any parameter changes.

I have create another goroutine in my main process listening on entreprise service, checking if the data have been updated

```
go func() {
 previousMachineGroups := machineGroupsModel
  for {
    time.Sleep(SECONDS_BETWEEN_CHECK * time.Second)
    newMachineGroups, errGet := getMachineGroupsFromEntreprise()
    if errGet != nil {
        log.Printf("| [reactor] error retrieving machine groups while checking for modification: %s", errGet)
        continue
    }
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(previousMachineGroups, newMachineGroups) {
        machineGroupsModel = newMachineGroups
    }
}
}()
```

Later in the code, in a loop I launch a goroutine (inside there is an infinite loop), that the data of this one I want to update

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for _, machineGroup := range machineGroupsModel {
 // some process
if machine.TargetNameCommandProgram.String != "" {
 checkIntervalSeconds := int(machineGroup.WaitBetweenCommandProgramCheckSeconds.Int64)
 wg.Add(1)
 go startMachineRoutine(*machine, machineGroup, checkIntervalSeconds, verbosityLevel, debug, &wg)
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify something for me? Is `startMachineRoutine` the one that will be changing the data that the first go routine is working on?  What I'm thinking is you can orchestrate this with a channel so that the go routine that has changed the data will send the changed data to the one that needs to modify it's behavior based on it.

Comment: No the data are modified by the user in the UI, `startMachineRoutine` The purpose of this function is to start a routine that watches for a command program on a machine. It does this by periodically checking for modifications to the command program and interpreting its contents to determine whether a load or unload command should be executed. If a command is detected, the appropriate action is taken.
i'm trying right now to make it work with channel, I think it's the best way to synchronize data but I haven't succeed yet.

Comment: So, does the question boil down to «How do I deliver an update collected by the "reactor" goroutine to goroutines running the `startMachineRoutine` function's code?»

Comment: use channel in reactor goroutine that send update to  startMachineRoutine